# Why do I get "The import cannot be resolved", even when I can find the class in the build path?

Tags: java, class, jar, buildpath

I have a jar file that I have included on my project's build path.  It contains a class file called aaf.class.  The class file holds the definition for the aaf class obviously.  When I try to **import aaf** in my java file, it says

> The import aaf cannot be resolved

Does anyone know why this would be happening as I am sure it is on the build path?  I have never seen this before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put it in your classpath. That should solve things.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the fully qualified package name is `aaf.class` you can't import from the default package. Simple as that.